# ClientWebSocketContainer - can it be used on the client side to create a websocket connection?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-websocket

The ClientWebSocketContainer Spring class can provide a websocket connection session to a remote endpoint. Though if an attempt is made to re-establish a closed connection (after a failed attempt) by using the ClientWebSocketContainer stop(), start(), and then getSession() methods, the connection is established but the ClientWebSocketContainer thinks it isn't connected due to the openConnectionException set in the failed attempt.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    logger.error("Failed to connect", t);
    ClientWebSocketContainer.this.openConnectionException = t;
    ClientWebSocketContainer.this.connectionLatch.countDown();
}
```

Should I be able to use the ClientWebSocketContainer in this fashion or should I create my own client connection manager?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a bug, some kind of omission in the `ClientWebSocketContainer` logic.

I've just raised a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4028) on the matter. Will be fixed today.

Meanwhile give us more information what is your task?

The `ClientWebSocketContainer` is based on the `ConnectionManagerSupport`, where one of its implementation is `WebSocketConnectionManager`. So, consider to use the last one for obtaining the session.

If you use Spring Integration WebSocket Adapters, you don't have choice unless implement your own `ClientWebSocketContainer` variant. Yes, it fully may be based on the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

I have an interesting situation where I need to connect to a server as a client and push data to the server. This is why I'm interested in obtaining the websocket session. IIRC the WebSocketConnectionManager has a session but doesn't provide a mechanism for accessing the session except via the message handler.

Comment: M-m-m. You really need to take a look into `<int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter>`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/web-sockets.html#web-socket-outbound-adapter. But be ready SI-4.2.6.RELEASE with the fix for your problem will be available tomorrow!

Comment: Hi M-m-m, I was considering the WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler but I couldn't determine how to reconnect the socket if the connection went down. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Yeah. You are right. There was no such a functionality. In a new version we restart the container for dead session on the next retrieval. I think that should meet your reality

Comment: Hi Artem, is the new version available?

Comment: I think so http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-integration-websocket